# Kendo UI Menu - Change text color of just top level not sub menu's?

Tags: colors, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I have a menu similar to the following:

```
---> Sport
    ---> Football
        ---> Players
        ---> Rules
    ---> Cricket
    ---> Baseball
---> Showbiz
```

And i just want to change the color of just the top level menu items 'Sport' and 'Showbiz'.
At the moment I am using:

```
.k-menu .k-item .k-link{
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

But this changes the color of the top level AND 'Football' because it has sub menu's. I don't want 'Football' to change though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following definition:

```
#menu > li.k-item > span.k-link{
    color:red !important;
}
```

Where `#menu` is the `id` of the top menu. With this, we limit the scope to the `li` that are hanging directly from the top list and the to the first links of it.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/zxpsk8zm/

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped however, one issue. Can you try and swap the position of both 'Sports' and 'Showbiz' because I just tried that (for sorting purposes) and the first menu option 'Showbiz' doesn't change color.